# MySQL delete data where field is contained in another table

Tags: mysql

I have a database with 2 tables like this (much larger than this)

```
users
Name      |     Email
Bill            billy@gmail.com
Susan           susan@gmail.com
```

-

```
bad_emails
Email
billy@gmail.com
bademail@gmail.com
```

I want to delete anything from users where the email is in the bad_emails table.

I tried something like this

`DELETE FROM users WHERE (SELECT Email FROM bad_emails) as bad_emails = users.Email`

But that's a syntax error, not sure on the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways.

`JOIN`:

```
DELETE u
FROM users AS u 
JOIN bad_emails AS b ON u.email = b.email
```

`WHERE IN`:

```
DELETE FROM users
WHERE email in (SELECT email FROM bad_emails)
```

`WHERE EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM users AS u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM bad_emails AS b WHERE b.email = u.email)
```